# How to import data into database using xml

Tags: android, xml, soap

I am trying to import data into the database using xml  by using soap services
     I done with following code but it is giving me error :
     **Unknown Request, cannot be processed**
     I am sending data in xml format from soap services please check 
      that and let me know  where i am mistaking

```
   Here is my code :

         String SOAP_ACTION = "http://LocalHOST/LISTOFLEDGERS/NAME";

         String URL = "http://LocalHOST:portname";
         String response = null;
         try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

            String bodyOut = "<soapenv:Envelope>"
                    + "<soapenv:Header>"
                    + "<soapenv:Version>1</soapenv:Version>"
                    + "<soapenv:Tallyrequest>Import</soapenv:Tallyrequest>"
                    + "<soapenv:Type>Data</soapenv:Type>"
                    + "<soapenv:Id>All Masters</soapenv:Id>"
                    + "</soapenv:Header>"
                    + "<soapenv:Body>"
                    + "<soapenv:Desc>"
                    + "<soapenv:Staticvariables>"
                    + "<soapenv:Svexportformat>$$SysName:XML</soapenv:Svexportformat>"
                    + "</soapenv:Staticvariables>" + "</soapenv:Desc>"
                    + "<soapenv:Data>" + "<soapenv:Tallymessage>"
                    + "<soapenv:Ledger Name=" + "" + "Travelling EXp" + ">"
                    + "<soapenv:NAME.LIST>"
                    + "<soapenv:NAME>EXp</NAME>"
                    + "</soapenv:NAME.LIST>" + "</soapenv:Ledger>"
                    + "</soapenv:Tallymessage>" + "</soapenv:DATA>"
                    + "</soapenv:BODY>" + "</soapenv:ENVELOPE>";

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(bodyOut, HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.v("getting response#######################", response);

   my xml one line is going +"<LEDGER NAME=EXp>"+ 
   it should be go like +"<LEDGER    NAME="EXp">"+ so how i can do that
```

Answer (score 1):

Use espace squence

[Java Escape Sequence](http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_Escape_Sequences.htm)

```
"<LEDGER    NAME=\"EXp\">"
```

Comment: thanks this works but still the error is same :Unknown Request, cannot be processed

Comment: now data is going in proper format but still error is same

Comment: I dont know SOAP so i can't help you anymore. But i suggest you to test the webservice by using this tool http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/ without developing. Maybe it gives you more detaied info about error